# physical vector representation

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have 3d two physical vectors with (x,y,z) and directions. I want do some operations on them. But I have some questions:

- How should I represent this vectors in c++ ?  In other words, I have wrote below class but I do not know how to represent direction in it ?

  ```
   class vector_ {
        float x,y,z ;
   }
  ```
- How can I calculate addition of two vectors ?  [image]

Comment: Use a library that does it for you, e.g. [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)

Comment: It's just adding element-wise. In c++ you can overload the `operator+`

Comment: The direction is represented by the values of `x`, `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you should provide for a 3D vector class:

1. Default construction
2. Construction from components
3. access to individual components (possibly in non-cartesian representations too)
4. vector-vector addition and subtraction
5. Scalar multiplication or "scaling"
6. vector-vector Scalar or [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)
7. vector-vector Vector or [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)
8. "Magnitude" or "length"

Item number 6 allows you to get the angle between two vectors, which presumably gives you the "direction" you mention in your question. It is customary to provide addition, subtraction, multiplication and division as non-member operators `+, -, *` and `/`. However, in the case of vectors, there are at least two commonly used multiplication operations (items 6 and 7) which are different and have different return values. So they are usually provided as non member functions. It is also usual to provide "increment" versions of some of the operations above ( `+=`, `-=` and `*=` for scalar multiplication. So, your vector class could look6something like this:

```
namespace geom 
{  //
class Vector3D
{
public:
  Vector3D() : x(0),y(0),z(0) {}
  Vector3D(float x,float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
  float x() { return x_; } // similarly for y() and z()
  Vector3D& operator +=(const Vector3D& rhs)
  {
    x_ += rhs.x_;
    y_ += rhs.y_;
    z_ += rhs.z_;
    return *this;

  }
  Vector3D& operator -=(const Vector3D& rhs)
  {
    // similar to above
  }
  template <typename Scalar>
  Vector3D& operator *=(const Scalar& scalar)
  {
    x_ *+ scalar;
    // similar for y_ and z_
    return *this;
  }
private:
 float x_, y_, z_:
};
```

and some of your non-member functions:

```
namespace geom 
{
Vector3D operator + (const Vector3D& lhs, const Vector3D& rhs)
{
  return Vector3D( lhs.x() + rhs.x(), lhs.y() + rhs.y(), lhs.z() + rhs.z() );

}
// similarly for operator -

template <typename Scalar>
Vector3D operator*(const Scalar& scalar, const Vector3D& vect)
{
  return Vector(scalar*vect.x(), scalar*vect.y(), scalar*vect.z());
}

template <typename Scalar>
Vector3D operator*(const Vector3D& vect, const Scalar& scalar)
{
  return scalar*vect;
}

float dot(const Vector3D& lhs, const Vector3D& rhs) { /* implement dot product */ }

Vector3D cross(const Vector3D& lhs, const Vector3D& rhs) { /* implement cross product */ }
} // namespace geom
```

Answer (score 1):

As fas as I can recall my mathematics from my school years - the vector direction is just sign  of its values:

For 1D case these two 1D vectors are of the same value but opposite directions:

```
{11.21}  {-11.21}
```

For 2D vectors you have 2 directions - these 4 vectors are of different directions:

```
{1,2} {-1,2} {1,-2} {-1,-2}
```

And for 3D vectors is has 3 different directions, so I would use simple `std::array<float,3>`:

```
typedef std::array<float,3> Vector3D;
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array:

Or use std::tuple http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple:

```
typedef std::tuple<float,float,float> Vector3D;
```

For adding use `std::transform` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform:

```
inline Vector3D operator + (const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b)
{
   Vector3D c;
   std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), c.begin(), 
               [](float a, float b){return a + b;});
   return c;
}
```

For your example see [ideone example](http://ideone.com/gqThD)

Comment: A 3D vector can have many representations, so it might be better to use a dedicated class with methods that clearly indicate the representation.

Comment: @juanchopanza I wouldn't use extra class, just typedef is enough with operators, but that is my personal approach and opinion,

Comment: @PiotrNycz accessing mathematical vector elements by name is an advantage, using abstract constructs like `v[0]` do not help readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the sample C++ Geometric Vector class found online it has all the neccessary functions required to create and modify vectors and perform various operations on them. http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0301/algorithm_0301.htm

This is a very powerful library to perform geometric operations in C++ http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Introduction/Chapter_main.html

Alternatively you can try using constructors to define the vectors and write functions to calculate its angle from origin and all. Remember all the constants of a vector are orthogonal so you can find all properties like direction, magnitude using just these 3 values.

```
class vector{
 float x, y, z;
 public:
 vactor(float x, float y, float z){
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
  this->z = z;

 }

 static float angleToOrigin(vector v){
  // calculate angle to origin
 }
}
```

Comment: C++ vectors and geometric vectors are very different things and it's unlikely you'll ever use a `std::vector` to implement a geometric vector (you can but it's quite inefficient)

Comment: Oh thanks, sorry for the wrong link I posted. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a Vector class such as

```
class Vector
{
  float x,y,z ;
  Vector():x(0),y(0),z(0){}
  Vector(float x_,float y_, float z_):x(x_),y(y_),z(z_){}
  Vector(const Vector& copyfrom)
  {
    this->x=copyfrom.x;this->y=copyfrom.y;this->z=copyfrom.z;
  }
  friend Vector operator+ <> (const Vector& a,const Vector& b)
  {
    Vector temp;
    temp.x=a.x+b.x;temp.y=a.y+b.y;temp.z=a.z+b.z;
    return temp;
 }
}
```

Once you override the equal operator, then you can write Vector a(1,1,1) and Vector b(2,2,2) and Vector c=a+b;

Comment: no reason for the friend, if you have public access to the components, and a 3 component constructor.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, you are right! The correct syntax should be Vector operator+ (const Vector& a,const Vector& b)